# С#: расшифровка 8bit сообщения

Tags: c#, email, smtp

Добрый день.

Я написал свой СМТП-сервер, он работает, но на него иногда приходят сообщения в формате:

> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Вот сам текст сообщения:

> Received: ****************************************************
>     ************************************* Sat,  4 Jun 2016 10:48:34 +0300
>   (EEST) Date: Sat, 4 Jun 2016 10:48:34 +0300 (EEST) From: from@mail.ru
>   To: to@mail.ru Message-ID: 1354354354354354374354343438434384348448
>   Subject:  MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=Windows-1251 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit X-Mailer:
>   ColdFusion 9 Application Server X-MCServiceID: 22 X-SMSPriority: Low
>
> Sample Message ?????? ?????? ???????  ????????? ?.?. - (?????????) .

Я получаю текст сообщения через сокет и перевожу его в текст:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b)
```

Я вычитал, что `8bit - Это значение указывает, что данные в теле сообщения содержат знаки, которых нет в кодировке US-ASCII`

Может, это не у СМТП проблема?
**Или  если у него, как можно решить вопрос?**

Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, `Encoding.ASCII` выглядит как-то не очень. Вы не должны угадывать кодировку (тем более, что предположение о том, что это ASCII, явно нереалистичное: письма вполне могут могут быть, например, на русском). Разберите заголовок письма (только не регулярками, пожалуйста), найдите там правильную кодировку (в вашем случае CP1252), и декодируйте сообщение правильно.

Comment: Я получаю массив байтов из сокета, чтобы прочитать заголовок, нужно его как-то конвертнуть в текст. Т.е. Вы предлаагете еще раз конвертирвоат ьмассив байтов в кодировке CP1252, да ?

Comment: По идее, да. Вы сохраняете байты, конвертируете в ASCII, разбираете до тех пор, пока не найдёте реальную кодировку, после чего конвертируете те же исходные байты снова. Хотя лучше, конечно, заглянуть в RFC, чтобы быть уверенным.

Comment: Или возможно у заголовка отдельная кодировка, и его нужно обрабатывать отдельно. Загляните в RFC, и правда.

Comment: вот тут увидел ответ. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710599/content-transfer-encoding-7bit-or-8-bit
Проблема как у тебя